# Is it possible to create 'grouped' fields of related data?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a content type (Recipe) in which my users can add ingredients (terme references). I also have a text field to enter quantity
How is it possible to link this "ingredient" field to the quatity field?

I want to recreate something like this (from Recipe module) : 
[image: recipe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module OR [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module

Example (from paragraphs):

[image]

Then with a little CSS magic, you can put them side by side, if you really want it like that.

Comment: Field Collection + table module did the trick :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Drupal 7 I would advise using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) to do this. I have done it many times, and for a generic use case of 'bundled' or 'grouped' fields, this is precisely what you want. Note that you will have to redo these fields (pictured above) and define them in a collection. Then, every collection entity holds X fields, therefore, each collection entity is in this case, one ingredient of the recipe.

If you are running an ecommerce store, you can get creative with these as well by adding a product reference, for example, if you sell the ingredients. That is, you can add collection fields that are not displayed publicly, but used to drive other content displays based on relationships.

Just know that the difficulty in theming field collection data might throw you for a loop at first, as well as searching/Views with collections.

You will also want to pick up [Field Collection Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) module so the field is formatted in a table for editing or display.